# Software quality attributes including usability, performance

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, software

I need a dataset of software quality attributes, preferably with the classes 'usability', 'performance' and so on.

I already have "AWARE_Aspect-Based_Sentiment_Analysis_Dataset_of_Apps_Reviews_for_Requirements_Elicitation" dataset but it doesn't have the class 'Performance'

Comment: These quality attributes should be rated by human users of the software, based on their experience with the software, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Not exactly! Dataset should contain user reviews/comments of any application from app store, every review should either be labelled as 'usability', 'performance', 'reliability' and so on. These attributes are to be labelled by experienced software engineers.

Comment: I see, thanks! Would you mind making that extra clear in the question, in order to attract answers that really help you? Comments will get deleted. By the way welcome to this site! :-)